# Populate model with Hibernate omitting some fields

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to do a query to the database and I don't know exactly how to do it.

I have an entity Article and an entity Tag. One article can have multiple tags. If I retrieve the whole article from the DB the list of tags is properly found in the articleTags field from the Article entity.

From Article:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference("article-articleTags")
private Set<ArticleTag> articleTags;
```

From ArticleTag ( the intermediary model ) :

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
@JsonBackReference("article-articleTags")
private Article article;
```

And Tag :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
@JsonBackReference("tags-articleTags")
private Set<ArticleTag> articleTags;
```

In ArticleDaoImpl, the following `query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Article a where a.link = "foo.bar"` populate the entity with all the collections that are mapped to Article.

The problem is that I have an field, html_content which is a blob containing the html content of the article. This is a performance downfall an what I want to do is to retrieve the data from Article table( including the mapped collections ) but without this field.

If I create a custom constructor in Article, than get the needed data, I don't know how to populate the collections.

I don't want to make two separated queries (retrieve the partial Article and that it's tags) and that is why I am asking if is a possibility of doing what I want to achieve.

**EDIT:**

Using @Basic annotation won't help because Jackson is doing a call to the database when it tries to serialize to the JSP. I don't want to use @JsonIgnore because I need that field sometimes in my JSP.
I may not be clear of what I'm trying to do:

- in 90% of my cases I want the article in JSP without htmlContent.
- but I also don't want that field to be retrieved from the DB, so I want that to be somehow lazy fetched and when I have something like this 
  `article.htmlContent` in the JSP, only then a call to the database to happen;

As a note: I have the Open Session in View patter implemented so I can access lazy fields from JSP.

Comment: How about marking the BLOB field with `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` to make it lazy loaded. Wouldn't that solve your performance concern?

Comment: I don't understand your architecture. If you're using a JSP to render a view from the article, when does Jackson serialize the article? What is Jackson used for? Also, your query doesn't fetch an article with its tags. It fetches an article, and then later, lazily, the articleTags collection is populated using a second query.

Comment: Jackson is used to stop the infinite recursion between Article and Tag class through ArticleTag list which is contained by both entities with the help of these two annotations JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference.  I know that the query for articleTags is after the one for article. So basically I want that the field `html_content` to be Lazy initialized and in my jsp when I will need it to retrieve it without problem. Json is clearly break my lazy init of the `html_content` field when it's doing the serialization.